# SmtpClient SendAsync error

Tags: c#, email, asynchronous, smtp, rabbitmq

**BACKGROUND**

I have written a little console application that monitors a RabbitMQ queue for emails. Whenever an email is pushed onto the queue, my application would pick up that email, process it and send it.

**CODE**

Below is the code for my email service, it is what actually sends out the email.

```
public class MailService : IMailService
{
    private readonly SmtpClient _smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

    public void SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string body, bool isHtml)
    {
      var emailMessage = BuildEmailMessage(toEmail.Trim(), subject.Trim(), body, isHtml);
      _smtpClient.SendAsync(emailMessage, null);
    }

    #region Helpers
    private static MailMessage BuildEmailMessage(string toEmail, string subject, string body, bool isHtml)
    {
      const string fromEmailAddress = "james.brown@world.com";
      var emailMessage = new MailMessage(fromEmailAddress, toEmail, subject, body) { IsBodyHtml = isHtml };
      return emailMessage;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I had 2 emails on the RabbitMQ queue, and when I fired up my console application consumer, it threw the following exception after sending the first email (I received that 1st email in my inbox).

> An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.

I did some digging around, and saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369614/is-it-wise-to-use-smtp-sendasync-in-asp-net) which explains why I got this. Apparently using `SendAsync()` isn't the way to go because:

> After calling SendAsync, you must wait for the e-mail transmission to complete before attempting to send another e-mail message using Send or SendAsync.

So what is the recommend way of going about this? I can create a new instance of the `SmtpClient` class for each email, but is that really a good idea?

Comment: Why are you using `SendAsync` in the first place? Just use `Send`. If you really need async, you should refactor your code and call `await SendMailAsync` which means you need to asyncify all the way up the call stack.

Comment: @mason you mean leave my code as it is, and just using `.Send(message)` or should I wrap it in a `using()` statement?

Comment: It would be better to wrap  the `SmtpClient` in a using statement instead of keeping it as a field. But still, use `.Send(message)` instead of `SendAsync`, which is based on the old async patterns.

Comment: @mason that did it, please reply as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the email synchronously, there's no need to use the older async syntax of `SendAsync`. Also, ensure your `SmtpClient` only gets hit from one thread at a time by wrapping it in a using statement. There is a slight performance penalty, but you probably won't notice it unless you're sending a ton of emails. And if you are sending a ton, then overload your `MailService.SendEmail` method to accept an `IEnumerable<EmailModel>` and send them all at once using a single SmtpClient.

```
public void SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string body, bool isHtml)
{
    var emailMessage = BuildEmailMessage(toEmail.Trim(), subject.Trim(), body, isHtml);

    using(var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        _smtpClient.Send(emailMessage);
    }      
}

//this would be the right way to do async
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string subject, string body, bool isHtml)
{
    var emailMessage = BuildEmailMessage(toEmail.Trim(), subject.Trim(), body, isHtml);

    using(var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        _smtpClient.SendMailAsync(emailMessage);
    }      
}


//this would be the right way to do multiple emails
//you'd need to create an EmailModel class to contain all the details for each email (similar to MailMessage, but it would prevent your own code from taking a dependency on System.Net.Mail
public void SendEmail(IEnumerable<EmailModel> emailModels)
{

    var mailMessages = emailModels.Select(em =>  ConvertEmailModelToMailMessage(em));

    using(var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        foreach(var mailMessage in mailMessages)
        {
            //you may want some error handling on the below line depending on whether you want all emails to attempt to send even if one encounters an error
            _smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }      
}

private MailMessage ConvertEmailModelToMailMessage(EmailModel emailModel)
{
    //do conversion here
}
```